# Change from master to development branch in SmartGit

Tags: git, branch, smartgit

I clone a repo using SmartGit but now following good practices I'll start developing at `development` branch and then merge this one with master but I don't know how to change between them from SmartGit. See the image below:

[image: SmartGit]

There I made right click at `development` and click on `Rebase HEAD to` but this didn't work since my COMMIT was unsuccessful. How I change between branch on SmartGit? Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the branch you want to switch to in the **Branches** view and invoke **Branch > Check Out**.

Note: you should probably never rebase `master` onto `development` or vice versa.

Comment: I've clicked Check Out but I don't see the changes in my IDE. I'm using IntelliJ.